# Rails subdomains are not working

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, subdomain

I have modified etc/hosts to map app.website.local to my localhost 127.0.0.1. This works and it gets redirected to my localhost.

The problem is that `request.subdomain` is empty, so i can't do anything with it.

```
class ApplicationController
  before_filter :ensure_domain

  private 

  def ensure_domain
    # do something with the request 
    # here is request.subdomain empty
  end
end
```

my etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
127.0.0.1 app.website.local
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I solved the problem myself. I took this project of somebody in the uk. There they use co.uk for domain names. He added the following config in development.rb

```
config.action_dispatch.tld_length = 3
```

Deleting this line solved it.